# Finding $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Find the derivative with respect to x for the following function:

$\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{-1}$

Comment: Start with $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1}=\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$. Then use the chain rule to take the derivative.

Answer (score 5):

$$f= \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{-1}$$

$$f_x= -1(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-2}\cdot 2x$$

$$f_x= \frac{-2x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $f(x)=1/(x^2+a)$. Then $f'(x)=(-2x)/(x^2+a)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ f=(u(x))^n\\f'=n(u(x))^{n-1}(u(x))'\\$$so$$f=u^{-1}\\f'=-1u^{-2}u' $$